# Один виджет autocomplete за время работы со страницей

Tags: jquery-ui

На странице много элементов *input type='text'* по выбору какого либо элемента он должен стать виджетом autocomplete, но мне необходимо обеспечить что бы за все время работы со страницей виджет был в единственном экземпляре.

```
$('input').bind('focus',function (event){
    //Здесь нужно удалить все autocomplete

    $(this).autocomplete({source: dict,});  // А потом создать только один
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А собственно для чего Вам это? И почему Вы добавляете функционал autocomplete по событию получения фокуса? Вообще говоря предполагается, что autocomplete ставится один раз для всех элементов при загрузке страницы (в `$(function() { ... });` ).

А в дальнейшем у Вас и будет работать только один autocomplete, а остальные спрятаны и совсем не мешают.

Comment: Это не моя воля, так написано в ТЗ, не думаю что стоит искать другие выходы.

Comment: Интересно, что именно там написано. Может быть стоит попробовать выполнить буквально?

Хотя Вы уверены, что правильно поняли требование "удалить"? Может быть все же имелось в виду, что будет закрыто всплывающее окно? Так ведь это будет сделано на автомате. 

Да даже если и действительно удалить, то возникает вопрос - кто писал ТЗ? И поймет ли он разницу, если Вы все таки скроете всплывшее окно, а не будете его удалять.